# Map is better or enum is better on performance grounds?

Tags: java, dictionary, enums

I am new to using Enum.I am using Maps since long time.
I am not to sure and not too clear about Enum performance and capabilities.
Is it something to do with the performance if i use enum?
is it more kind of ObjectOriented using Enum?

Wanted a clear Idea about both of it on the grounds of their internal structure.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Enum values can't be changed in runtime. It's hardcoded set of values more like wrapper around set of constants. And map is a collection where you can store dynamic data based on key

Comment: If you presented one specific use case where you are using maps now and considering enums, you may at least stand a chance of giving us an inkling of an idea what your actual question is.

Comment: Thanks folks Your answer really helped me to increase my knowledge base and basic understanding about both of these data Structures.

conclusion(for rest of the users): 

Maps and enums are completely different data structures. Maps are for associating a value with a key. Enums are for make typesafe constants.
Enum values can't be changed in runtime. It's hardcoded set of values more like wrapper around set of constants. And map is a collection where you can store dynamic data based on key.

well in my case i would use Maps because I am flooding values from the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps and enums are completely different data structures. Maps are for associating a value with a key. Enums are for make typesafe constants. Comparing the two is impossible!